# Requesting controller action via Curl request

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, controllers, curl-request

I am sending a CURL request to a controller action and `construct()` function is working (called) but it doesn't call the `execute()` function of the controller.

For now, I am calling the `execute()` function within the `construct()` myself as below. Also, let me know if it is not a recommended way.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    $this->execute();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

First, it's not the recommended way. 
If your application need to talk to Magento, the best way to use Rest/GraphQl API for this.

See, official documentation.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Actually, all that you need is create class and then map methods of thous class to some endpoint in `webapi.xml`

Comment: Actually I am implementing a Custom Payment module and A curl call will be triggered from the Payment server to Magento in a case So that It is necessary for me to handle that curl call. If I use Rest API few functions are not working properly. Is there any other way to do this.